# Qlikview load from excel specific row

Tags: excel, row, qlikview

I have excel and i need to import in qlikview wtih specific ruls.
This is excel file

[excel file for import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urcTk.png)

I need in one table to get data from row 1 to row 8 included 8,
in second table to get data from row 9 to row 17...
and so on to the end of the file.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use `RowNo()` when loading the entire file to a temporary table, then you can create new tables from that table using the generated row numbers.